# Adding an argument/variable in `sequencediagram` (pgf-umlsd)

Tags: optional-arguments, tikz-uml, pgf-umlcd

My aim is to have the possiblity to configure in the figure tex either if the vertical bar of a sequence diagram is dotted, plain, thick, etc. 
Depending on the diagram, I wish I could have the choice between these options.

So far, I identified the location and the way I wish to organize the code. Indeed, I would like to know if it possible to add an option of :

```
\begin{sequencediagram}[OPTION]
```

where OPTION could be "dotted", "thick" or empty (for simple bars b)

I noticed that the line of `pgf-umlsd.sty` ([link](http://pgf-umlsd.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pgf-umlsd.sty)) for displaying this bars is line 321 :

```
\draw[OPTION] (inst\t) -- ++(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-2.2*\unitfactor);
```

When I edit them by hand replacing OPTION by nothing, "dotted" or "thik", it works as expected in the figure. But I would like to make it configurable in the main tex.

So, now I don't know how to "code" this option, as a variable. Is there a simple way for doing it ?

---

**MINIMUM WORKING EXAMPLE**.

*main.tex :*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}
\newthread{a}{:A}
\newinst{b}{:B}

\begin{call}{a}{getStuff()}{b}{}
\end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

*uml-pgf.sty* :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Start of pgf-umlsd.sty
%
% Some macros for UML Sequence Diagrams.
% Home page of project: http://pgf-umlsd.googlecode.com/
% Author: Xu Yuan <xuyuan.cn@gmail.com>, Southeast University, China
% Contributor: Nobel Huang <nobel1984@gmail.com>, Southeast University, China
%
% History:
% v0.6 2011/07/27
%      - Fix Issue 6 reported by frankmorgner@gmail.com
%        - diagram without a thread
%        - allows empty diagram
%      - New manual
% v0.5 2009/09/30 Fix Issue 2 reported by vlado.handziski
%      - Nested callself is supported
%      - Rename sdloop and sdframe to sdblock
% v0.4 2008/12/08  Fix Issue 1 reported by MathStuf:
%      Nested sdloop environment hides outer loop
% v0.3 2008/11/10 in Berlin, fix for the PGF cvs version:
%      - the list items in \foreach are not evaluated by default now,
%      the `evaluate' opinion should be used
% v0.2 2008/03/20 create project at http://pgf-umlsd.googlecode.com/
%      - use `shadows' library
%      Thanks for Dr. Ludger Humbert's <humbert@uni-wuppertal.de> feedback!
%      - reduce the parameter numbers, the user can write the content
%      of instance (such as no colon)
%      - the user can redefine the `inststyle'
%      - new option: switch underlining of the instance text
%      - new option: switch rounded corners
% v0.1 2008/01/25 first release at http://www.fauskes.net/pgftikzexamples/
%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{pgf-umlsd}[2009/09/30 v0.5 Some LaTeX macros for UML
Sequence Diagrams.]

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shadows}

% Options
% ? the instance name under line ?
\newif\ifpgfumlsdunderline\pgfumlsdunderlinetrue
\DeclareOption{underline}{\pgfumlsdunderlinetrue}
\DeclareOption{underline=true}{\pgfumlsdunderlinetrue}
\DeclareOption{underline=false}{\pgfumlsdunderlinefalse}
% ? the instance box with rounded corners ?
\newif\ifpgfumlsdroundedcorners\pgfumlsdroundedcornersfalse
\DeclareOption{roundedcorners}{\pgfumlsdroundedcornerstrue}
\DeclareOption{roundedcorners=true}{\pgfumlsdroundedcornerstrue}
\DeclareOption{roundedcorners=false}{\pgfumlsdroundedcornersfalse}
\ProcessOptions

% declare layers
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{threadground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,threadground,main}

% new counters
\newcounter{preinst}
\newcounter{instnum}
\newcounter{threadnum}
\newcounter{seqlevel} % level
\newcounter{callevel}
\newcounter{callselflevel}
\newcounter{blocklevel}

% new an instance
% Example:
% \newinst[edge distance]{var}{name:class}
\newcommand{\newinst}[3][0.2]{
  \stepcounter{instnum}
  \path (inst\thepreinst.east)+(#1,0) node[inststyle] (inst\theinstnum)
  {\ifpgfumlsdunderline
    \underline{#3}
  \else
  #3
  \fi};
  \path (inst\theinstnum)+(0,-0.5*\unitfactor) node (#2) {};
  \tikzstyle{instcolor#2}=[]
  \stepcounter{preinst}
}

% new an instance thread
% Example:
% \newinst[color]{var}{name}{class}
\newcommand{\newthread}[3][gray!30]{
  \newinst{#2}{#3}
  \stepcounter{threadnum}
  \node[below of=inst\theinstnum,node distance=0.8cm] (thread\thethreadnum) {};
  \tikzstyle{threadcolor\thethreadnum}=[fill=#1]
  \tikzstyle{instcolor#2}=[fill=#1]
}

% draw running (thick) line, should not call directly
\newcommand*{\drawthread}[2]{
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{threadground}
    \draw[threadstyle] (#1.west) -- (#1.east) -- (#2.east) -- (#2.west) -- cycle;
  \end{pgfonlayer}
}

% a function call
% Example:
% \begin{call}[height]{caller}{function}{callee}{return}
% \end{call}
\newenvironment{call}[5][2]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \stepcounter{callevel} % push
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (cf\thecallevel) {}
  (#4.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (ct\thecallevel) {};

  \draw[->,>=triangle 60] ({cf\thecallevel}) -- (ct\thecallevel)
  node[midway, above] {#3};
  \def\l\thecallevel{#1}
  \def\f\thecallevel{#2}
  \def\t\thecallevel{#4}
  \def\returnvalue{#5}
  \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[instcolor#2]
}
{
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{\l\thecallevel}
  \path
  (\f\thecallevel)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (rf\thecallevel) {}
  (\t\thecallevel.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (rt\thecallevel) {};
  \draw[dashed,->,>=angle 60] ({rt\thecallevel}) -- (rf\thecallevel)
  node[midway, above]{\returnvalue};
  \drawthread{ct\thecallevel}{rt\thecallevel}
  \addtocounter{callevel}{-1} % pop
}

% a function do not need call others
% Example:
% \begin{callself}[height]{caller}{function}{return}
% \end{callself}
\newenvironment{callself}[4][3]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \stepcounter{callevel} % push
  \stepcounter{callselflevel}

  \path
  (#2)+(\thecallselflevel*0.1-0.1,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (sc\thecallevel) {}
  ({sc\thecallevel}.east)+(0,-0.33*\unitfactor) node (scb\thecallevel) {};

  \draw[->,>=triangle 60] ({sc\thecallevel}.east) -- ++(0.8,0)
  node[near start, above right] {#3} -- ++(0,-0.33*\unitfactor)
  -- (scb\thecallevel); 
  \def\l\thecallevel{#1}
  \def\f\thecallevel{#2}
  \def\returnvalue{#4}
  \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[instcolor#2]
}{
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{\l\thecallevel}
  \path (\f\thecallevel)+(\thecallselflevel*0.1-0.1,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.33*\unitfactor) node
  (sct\thecallevel) {};

  \draw[dashed,->,>=angle 60] ({sct\thecallevel}.east) node
  (sce\thecallevel) {} -- ++(0.8,0) -- node[midway, right]{\returnvalue} ++(0,-0.33*\unitfactor) -- ++(-0.8,0);
  \drawthread{scb\thecallevel}{sce\thecallevel}
  \addtocounter{callevel}{-1} % pop
  \addtocounter{callselflevel}{-1}
}

% message between threads
% Example:
% \mess{sender}{message content}{receiver}
\newcommand{\mess}[3]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \path
  (#1)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (messbeg) {}
  (#3)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (messend) {};
  \draw[->,>=angle 60] (messbeg) -- (messend) node[midway, above] {#2};
}

\newenvironment{messcall}[4][4]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \stepcounter{callevel} % push
  \path
  (#2)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (cf\thecallevel) {}
  (#4.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (ct\thecallevel) {};

  \draw[->,>=angle 60] ({cf\thecallevel}) -- (ct\thecallevel)
  node[midway, above] {#3};
  \def\l\thecallevel{#1}
  \def\f\thecallevel{#2}
  \def\t\thecallevel{#4}
  \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[instcolor#2]
}
{
  \addtocounter{seqlevel}{\l\thecallevel}
  \path
  (\f\thecallevel)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.7*\unitfactor) node (rf\thecallevel) {}
  (\t\thecallevel.\threadbias)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.3*\unitfactor) node (rt\thecallevel) {};
  \drawthread{ct\thecallevel}{rt\thecallevel}
  \addtocounter{callevel}{-1} % pop
}

% In the situation of multi-threads, some objects are called at the
% same time. Currently, we have to adjust the bias of thread line
% manually. Possible parameters are: center, west, east
\newcommand{\setthreadbias}[1]{\global\def\threadbias{#1}}

% In the situation of multi-threads, some events happen at the same
% time. Currently, we have to adjust the level(time) of events
% manually. This function makes the call earlier.
\newcommand{\prelevel}{\addtocounter{seqlevel}{-1}}

% a block box with caption
% \begin{sdblock}[caption background color]{caption}{comments}
% \end{sdblock}
\newenvironment{sdblock}[3][white]{
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \stepcounter{blocklevel} % push
  \coordinate (blockbeg\theblocklevel) at (0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-\unitfactor);
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
  \def\blockcolor\theblocklevel{#1}
  \def\blockname\theblocklevel{#2}
  \def\blockcomm\theblocklevel{#3}
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
}{
  \coordinate (blockend) at (0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-2*\unitfactor);
  \path (current bounding box.east)+(0.2,0) node (boxeast) {}
  (current bounding box.west |- {blockbeg\theblocklevel}) + (-0.2,0)
  node (nw) {};
  \path (boxeast |- blockend) node (se) {};
  \draw (nw) rectangle (se);

  % title
  \node[blockstyle] (blocktitle) at (nw) {\blockname\theblocklevel};
  \path (blocktitle.south east) + (0,0.2) node (set) {}
  (blocktitle.south east) + (-0.2,0) node (seb) {}
  (blocktitle.north east) + (0.2,0) node (comm) {};
  \draw[fill=\blockcolor\theblocklevel] (blocktitle.north west) -- (blocktitle.north east) --
  (set.center) -- (seb.center) -- (blocktitle.south west) -- cycle;
  \node[blockstyle] (blocktitle) at (nw) {\blockname\theblocklevel};
  \node[blockcommentstyle] (blockcomment) at (comm) {\blockcomm\theblocklevel};

  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}

  % add two points to keep the bounding box
  \node[dot] (fnw) at (nw) {};
  \node[dot] (fse) at (se) {};

  \addtocounter{blocklevel}{-1} % pop
  \stepcounter{seqlevel}
}

% the environment of sequence diagram
\newenvironment{sequencediagram}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \tikzstyle{sequence}=[coordinate]
    \tikzstyle{inststyle}=[rectangle, draw, anchor=west, minimum
    height=0.8cm, minimum width=1.6cm, fill=white, 
    drop shadow={opacity=1,fill=black}]
    \ifpgfumlsdroundedcorners
    \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[rounded corners=3mm]
    \fi
    \tikzstyle{blockstyle}=[anchor=north west]
    \tikzstyle{blockcommentstyle}=[anchor=north west, font=\small]
    \tikzstyle{dot}=[inner sep=0pt,fill=black,circle,minimum size=0.2pt]
    \global\def\unitfactor{0.6}
    \global\def\threadbias{center}
    % reset counters
    \setcounter{preinst}{0}
    \setcounter{instnum}{0}
    \setcounter{threadnum}{0}
    \setcounter{seqlevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callselflevel}{0}
    \setcounter{blocklevel}{0}

    % origin
    \node[coordinate] (inst0) {};
}
{
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \ifnum\c@instnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\theinstnum}{
      \draw[dotted] (inst\t) -- ++(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-2.2*\unitfactor);
    }
    \fi
    \ifnum\c@threadnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\thethreadnum}{
      \path (thread\t)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.1*\unitfactor) node (threadend) {};
      \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[threadcolor\t]
      \drawthread{thread\t}{threadend}
    }
    \fi
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}


%%% End of pgf-umlsd.sty
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image: Output]

I wish these vertical dotted bar could be configurable as explained below.

---

**EXAMPLES**.

When the code of a sequence diagram is configured as  :

```
  \begin{sequencediagram}[]
```

The sequence vertical bar are simply plain.

If the code is :

```
  \begin{sequencediagram}[dotted]
```

The sequence vertical bar are dotted. Thick if the option is thick, etc.

Comment: Can you make a small example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: I was meaning a full example of a diagram (with solid lines), telling which ones you'd like to be dotted.

Comment: You may be at ease with `sequencediagram`, most of us probably not; a complete example will avoid trying to build one from the manual.

Comment: Now it is clear that you just want a thorough change in the package code. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg it's not a that "thorough". I don't know much latex coding, but in programming languages, it's usually simple to add some arguments to a function, as well easy to insert some variable inside a function. Or I may be mistaken, latex is probably more complex than that ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can renew the environment to accept an optional parameter whose default value will be `dotted`. In the opening definition, I store the parameter into the style `mygridstyle`, which is used in the closing definition in

```
\draw[mygridstyle] (inst\t) -- ...
```

This is required because the parameters of an environment may only be used in its opening, not in its closing.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-umlsd}

\makeatletter
% renew the environment of sequence diagram
\renewenvironment{sequencediagram}[1][dotted]{%
  % declare layers
  \pgfdeclarelayer{umlsd@background}%
  \pgfdeclarelayer{umlsd@threadlayer}%
  \pgfsetlayers{umlsd@background,umlsd@threadlayer,main}%

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
    \tikzstyle{sequence}=[coordinate]
    \tikzstyle{inststyle}=[rectangle, draw, anchor=west, minimum
    height=0.8cm, minimum width=1.6cm, fill=white, 
    drop shadow={opacity=1,fill=black}]
    \ifpgfumlsdroundedcorners%
    \tikzstyle{inststyle}+=[rounded corners=3mm]
    \fi
    \tikzstyle{blockstyle}=[anchor=north west]
    \tikzstyle{blockcommentstyle}=[anchor=north west, font=\small]
    \tikzstyle{dot}=[inner sep=0pt,fill=black,circle,minimum size=0.2pt]
    \tikzstyle{mygridstyle}=[#1]
    \global\def\unitfactor{0.6}
    \global\def\threadbias{center}
    % reset counters
    \setcounter{preinst}{0}
    \setcounter{instnum}{0}
    \setcounter{threadnum}{0}
    \setcounter{seqlevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callevel}{0}
    \setcounter{callselflevel}{0}
    \setcounter{blocklevel}{0}

    % origin
    \node[coordinate] (inst0) {};
}
{
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{umlsd@background}
    \ifnum\c@instnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\theinstnum}{
      \draw[mygridstyle] (inst\t) -- ++(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-2.2*\unitfactor);
    }
    \fi
    \ifnum\c@threadnum > 0
    \foreach \t [evaluate=\t] in {1,...,\thethreadnum}{
      \path (thread\t)+(0,-\theseqlevel*\unitfactor-0.1*\unitfactor) node (threadend) {};
      \tikzstyle{threadstyle}+=[threadcolor\t]
      \drawthread{thread\t}{threadend}
    }
    \fi
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{sequencediagram}[thick,dashed,blue]
\newthread{a}{:A}
\newinst{b}{:B}

\begin{call}{a}{getStuff()}{b}{}
\end{call}
\end{sequencediagram}

\end{document}
```

[image]